# Coloring figures with Turtle python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm fairly new to python and I have an assignment of creating this [Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUox8.png) with turtle in python. I've managed to create the figure, however there is one last thing I cannot figure out and that is that I need to color the triangles but they don't get colored no matter where I place the begin_fill().

```
from turtle import *
from math import *
from numpy import arange
#speed(3)
screensize(1200,1000)
tracer(False) #disables the turtle animation

start_x1 = -300
start_y1 = 0
side_length = 50 #defines that the side of each figure will be 50px
hexagon_height = float(sqrt(side_length**2-(side_length/2)**2)) #calculates the height of the hexagon
start_x2 = round(start_x1+hexagon_height + (side_length/2),2)
start_y2 = float((side_length/2)+hexagon_height+side_length)
distance_x = float(hexagon_height*2+side_length)#calculates the distance in the x-axis of each figure
distance_y = float(start_y2*2)


def draw_hexagon():

    color("black","black")
    begin_fill()
    seth(30)

    for i in range(6):
        left(60)
        forward(side_length)
    end_fill()

def draw_squares():

    for x in range (0,360,60):#This for loop increases the angle by 60 until 360 
        begin_fill()
        color('black','red')
        seth(x)#sets the initial angle to start drawing the square
        for i in range (3):
            forward(side_length)
            left(90)
        end_fill()
#This function draws the lines around the set hexagon+squares to form the triangles        

def draw_triangles():

    #begin_fill()
    #color('black','yellow')    
    seth(180)#these 3 lines position the turtle at the starting place to start drawing the triangles
    back(50)
    left(60)
    for i in range(12):#these lines draw the 12 sides of the triangles
        if i%2==0:
            begin_fill()
            color('black','yellow')
            forward(side_length)
            right(30) 
            end_fill()
        else:
            forward(side_length)
            right(30)

#this function creates two lines of figures starting at coordinates (-300,0) and (-300,236.6)
def create_line():

    for y in arange (start_y1,400,distance_y):#This will create the two lines of figures separated by 238 px in the y axis
        penup()
        for x in arange(start_x1,400,distance_x):#This will move the figures 136.6 pixels starting from the x position of -300 until it reaches x=400
            goto(x,y)#This moves the figures in the x and y axis 
            pendown()
            draw_hexagon()
            draw_squares()
            draw_triangles()

#this function creates one line of figures starting at coordinates (-231.7,118.3)        

def create_line2():

    for y in arange(start_y2,400,distance_y):
        penup()
        for x in arange(start_x2,476,distance_x):
            goto(x,y)
            pendown()
            draw_hexagon()
            draw_squares()
            draw_triangles()


create_line()

create_line2()
```

I tried adding in the function that creates the triangles an condition so that only the even triangles are colored but can't make it work.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, marked it as solved, thanks a lot for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you don't draw complete triangles. Comment out `draw_hexagon()` and `draw_squares()` and inspect the result:

[image]

At some point you have to draw a complete triangle. e.g.:

```py
begin_fill()
forward(side_length)
right(120)
forward(side_length)
right(120)
forward(side_length)
end_fill()
```

Draw the  triangle in case of `i%2==0:`

```py
def draw_triangles():

    color('black','yellow')  
    seth(180)#these 3 lines position the turtle at the starting place to start drawing the triangles
    back(50)
    left(60)
    for i in range(12):#these lines draw the 12 sides of the triangles
        if i%2==0:
            color('black','yellow')

            # draw filled triangle
            begin_fill()
            forward(side_length)
            right(120)
            forward(side_length)
            right(120)
            forward(side_length)
            end_fill()

            right(120)
            forward(side_length)
            right(30) 
        else:
            forward(side_length)
            right(30)
```

[image]
[image]